# Grunt | Could not find an option named "line-numbers" | dart-sass

Tags: node.js, grunt-contrib-sass

i'm using grunt for compiling sass, whis was working fine for a long time but now, i'm facing this issue.

Recently i clean installed my laptop and started it fresh, now i'm getting this issue. So any one can please help me with this.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    ...
    sass: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded',
          lineNumbers: true,
          sourcemap: 'none',
          update: true
        }
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit late - but I had this exact issue after installing sass via npm - I removed it and installed using `gem install sass` and everything then worked as expected.